# Hide Menu by Default in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

Is there a way to make Adobe Reader 10 not display the menu bar (File, etc.) initially, when opening files? Even when you disable it in `View>Show/Hide>Menu Bar` or with F9, the next time you open Acrobat Reader, it reappears. Is there any way to make this persistant?

I rarely need it, and have to press F9 every time I launch it. This is under Windows, of course.

Comment: I looked hard, especially on the Adobe Forums, but I am not sure you can, and the reason is that individual documents can, and probably are, re-enabling it (I sense that it is the default). Note the menu item "Edit>Preferences>Documents>Allow documents to hide the menu bar..."

Comment: By default, documents *do* show the menu bar.  If you create custom PDFs, or use a typesetting language (e.g. LaTeX), you are given the option to hide the menu bar from the end user when viewing the document.  And just another FYI, while I do enjoy Adobe software, I have tried some alternative PDF viewers and have found that they outperform Adobe's by quite a good performance margin (especially when searching).  [/plug for better free software]

Comment: @KCotreau I'm on Reader DC (the latest as of now) and I tried disabling that option (named "Allow documents to hide the menu bar, toolbars, and window controls"). The menu bar still appears when relaunching the Reader. Note that this also occurs when I launch the Reader from the start menu (without opening any document) so it's not due to documents telling Reader to show menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer from this link, it is not possible to hide it by default in Adobe Reader DC.
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/is-it-possible-to-permanently-hide-the-menu-tools-bar-in-acrobat.html
You can hide the tools, but not the menu.